# Google Maps API V3 window load eventListener not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, onload-event

A strange behaviour:
The last part of the [Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventListeners) on events inside maps API says that

```
>  If you've been reading the documentation this far, you're probably
> already familiar with one DOM event: the window.onload event, which
> we've handled within the <body> tag. We use this event to trigger the
> initial Javascript code once an HTML page is fully loaded, as shown
> below: <script>   function initialize() {
> 
>     // Map initialization
> 
>   } </script> <body onload="initialize()">   <div
> id="map_canvas"></div> </body> Although this event is attached to the
> <body> element here, this event is really a window event indicating
> that the DOM hierarchy below the window element has been fully built
> out and rendered. Although easy to understand, having an onload event
> within a <body> tag mixes content with behavior. Generally, it is good
> practice to separate your content code (HTML) from your behavioral
> code (Javascript) and provide your presentation code (CSS) separately
> as well. You can do so by replacing the inline onload event handler
> with a DOM listener within your Maps API Javascript code like so:
> <script>   function initialize() {
> 
>     // Map initialization
> 
>   }
>      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
> </script> <body>   <div id="map_canvas"></div> </body>
```

Somehow `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` doesn't work for Firefox/Safari, but  `<body onload="initialize()">` does...
Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work". Does it never run, or does it throw an error?

Comment: It does not initiate (from the google maps event listenter)

Comment: Can you link to a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem? I've not had any trouble with addDomListener before, so there may be a secondary cause.

Comment: FWIW I'm running across the same problem with Chrome so the issue is not limited to Safari/Firefox

Comment: Its been quite sometime, I just tried a fiddle.And it works like this  http://jsfiddle.net/DK7aG/